# Not getting Push notifications with Adhoc Profile (getting same token)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to QA the push process using production.  In development push is working perfectly.  I have generated the appropriate production certificates and uploaded them to the server.  I have created an adHoc profile as I know this is the only way to test push in a production environment without sending it to the store.  There are no server-side errors and again the code is the same that worked in development sans the different certs.  I was led to believe that adHoc/production tokens would be different than development; however, my device is returning the same token under adHoc as it did under development.

I am checking the device token in the AppDelegate.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    self.apnToken = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken]
                           stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"token"
                                                   message:self.apnToken
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Again when running under the standard debug build and the adHoc build, the device returns the same token.  In the end  I am not getting any push notifications with the adHoc build.  If the tokens are to be different than I am unclear why the alert (and the server) shows them the same.  If not, what else is preventing me from getting production pushes in adHoc mode knowing the certs and the server are working?

Comment: "There are no server-side errors..." - does this mean the connection to APNS is not terminated and no error code (e.g. 8) is returned? Also, could you explain your conversion from `deviceToken` to `self.apnToken`?

Comment: That is correct with regards to the server.  The messages from the server using the prod certs are the exact same as using the development certs.  With regards to the device token, I am simply taking the spaces out as well as the starting and ending "<>" signs.  The value coming from the raw token doesn't work as formatted.  This conversion is the same as worked in development.

Comment: When you push to the adhoc build using the dev push server & cert, it works right? So an ad-hoc build will only work with the dev?

Comment: Did you regenerate the provisioning profile and rebuild with the new one after enabling production push on Apple website ?

Comment: To add onto Mickaël's comment, your adhoc push token should really be different. You may also want to check that you're really building an AdHoc build.

Comment: The issue turned out to be on the server side.  As there was no error it was a difficult one to troubleshoot.  That said and the tokens are still the same from development to production.  It is working now in both environments so I know the certs for each work.  Yet, the the tokens are the same.